# json field on mysql where clause

Tags: mysql, json, select

How can I get data that contains `apiData` and inside `"method":"transfer"`

My field name is detail and it contains this data:

```
{"paymentMethodData":{"id":"3","api_id":"2","account_id":null,"account_ids":null,"installment_state":null,"name_1":"Havale"},"apiData":{"id":"2","method":"transfer","name":"Havale"}}
```

This query works but if other options contains `"method":"transfer"`, it gets. It shouldn't get data. If it has `apiData` option and inside `"method":"transfer"`, it should get:

```
SELECT * FROM task_payment_actions AS tpa
INNER JOIN task_payment_action_detail AS tpad ON tpad.task_payment_action_id=tpa.id
WHERE tpad.detail REGEXP '(.*\"method\":\"transfer\".*)'
```

Comment: Why don't you parse the JSON expression and query exactly what you need. If MySQL `REGEXP` is the answer, there probably is something wrong with the question.

Comment: If the data has only `{"paymentMethodData":{...,"method":"transfer",...}}`, it shouldn't get. Only if has `{"apiData":{...,"method":"transfer",..}}`, it should get the data

Comment: Yes, you probably have a middle language, that you use to query the database. Why don't you parse/decode the JSON string and check if under apiData there is "method" => "transfer" instead of trying to match it with `REGEXP`.

Comment: Because the table has many records and I will paginate results :s

Comment: That has nothing to do with the proposed solution. You do not make pagination with `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
As you said your method:"transfer" should be inside apiData I have make regexp according to your given string.

```
REGEXP '.*"apiData":{[",a-zA-Z0-9]*"method":"transfer"'
REGEXP '.*"apiData":{[",a-zA-Z0-9]*"method":"transfer"[",a-zA-Z0-9]*}'
```