# How to handle json inside a mysql query

Tags: mysql, json, wordpress, fpdf

This might seem over complicated but it's as close as I can get to my goal. I saw this question: [json field on mysql where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180954/json-field-on-mysql-where-clause) but it wasn't answered.

I'm working on wordpress with advanced custom fields and I need to generate a PDF that will contain a table with the posts in my database. I used fpdf to achieve this (http://www.fpdf.org/). I need to show a table in the pdf that will jump to the next page when the list of posts is too long and there's a script for that (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php).

Everything works fine but I need to have columns with custom fields and I've used Advanced Custom Fields for them and I don't really know how to do the mysql query (I can't use a wordpress query, it won't work with the pdf script I linked before). If I query the custom field I need I will get a json string like this:

```
a:3:{s:10:"pa_medidas";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"pa_medidas";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:12:"pa_variacion";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:12:"pa_variacion";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"1";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:20:"pa_grupo-de-clientes";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:20:"pa_grupo-de-clientes";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"2";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}
```

In my pdf I should have columns for each of the data in my advanced custom fields.

This is the code that I use to generate the pdf:

```
$pdf = new PDF_MySQL_Table();
$title = 'Gestyre PDF';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically

$query = " SELECT  p.ID,
        p.post_title,
        pm1.meta_value AS first_field,
        pm2.meta_value AS second_field,
        pm3.meta_value AS third_field
    FROM    wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON (
            pm1.post_id = p.ID  AND
            pm1.meta_key    = 'gama'
        ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON (
            pm2.post_id = p.ID  AND
            pm2.meta_key    = '_product_attributes'
        ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm3 ON (
            pm3.post_id = p.ID  AND
            pm3.meta_key    = '_width'
        )
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and post_status = 'publish'";

$pdf->Table($query);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Output();
```

I don't know how else to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:3:{s:10:"pa_medidas";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"pa_medidas";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:12:"pa_variacion";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:12:"pa_variacion";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"1";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:20:"pa_grupo-de-clientes";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:20:"pa_grupo-de-clientes";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"2";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}
```

What you are seeing in not actually JSON, it's a `serialized` PHP object. It follows some of the conventions of JSON, but it's not the same thing. Just looking at the string, it would appear to be an array with a string and a few other nested arrays. If you use the [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function in PHP, you should get it the object back out as a PHP value.

To accomplish what you are trying to do in FPDF, you are liekly going to have the query the database yourself, assemble the records into a 2D array, and use the basic [Table](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm) classes in FPDF to do the output. I'm not sure there is a quick fix for it

Comment: to unserialize, take a look at  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: oh I see. The problem is I need to pass the raw query to the Table method to build the pdf. You can see it on the link. The problem if I build it myself is that I don't know how to paginate the pdf then